# Lorentz transformation implemented by a non-unitary operator.

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, unitarity, covariance

One often come across in QFT sentences like the following, for instance:

> ...under a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ implemented by the unitary
>   operator $U(\Lambda)$, a Dirac field transforms as
>
> $$ U(\Lambda)^{-1}\Psi(x)U(\Lambda) = D(\Lambda)
>  \Psi(\Lambda^{-1}x),$$ where the matrix $D$...

What would be the other case, i.e. implemented by a non-unitary operator? Is $N(x)$ an example of such an operator?

$N(x):=\mathrm{i}x+x^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Poincaré invariance** is a fundamental requirement of relativistic (quantum) physics. In particular if $U_g : {\cal H} \to {\cal H}$ represents the (non-necessarily linear) action of a Poincaré transformation $g$ on (normalized) vectors $\psi$ of the Hilbert space  $\cal H$ of the considered system,  **transition probabilities have to be preserved**:
$$|\langle U_g(\psi) | U_g(\phi) \rangle|^2 = |\langle \psi | \phi \rangle|^2 \quad \forall \psi, \phi \in {\cal H}\:, ||\psi||=||\phi||=1\:. \quad (1)$$
A celebrated theorem due to Wigner establishes that a (bijective) map $U : {\cal H} \to {\cal H}$ verifying (1) must necessarily be **linear and unitary** or **anti linear and anti unitary**, depending on the physical nature of the transformation.

Concerning **representations** of Poincaré group $\cal P$, by definition they have to satisfy, in addition to (1),  ${\cal P} \ni g \mapsto U_g$ with $U_g U_h = U_{g\cdot h}$ ($^*$) and $U_e = id$, where $\cdot$ is the group product in $\cal P$, just in view of the definition of group representation. In principle each $U_g$ has to be unitary or anti unitary.

If $g\in \cal P$ belongs to the proper orthochronous subgroup ${\cal P}_+^\uparrow$,   it can always be decomposed as $g= h\cdot h$ where $h$ still belongs to the same subgroup. Therefore $U_g= U_{h} U_{h}$, thus $U_g$ must be unitary (even if $U_h$ is anti unitary,as the composition of a pair of anti unitary operator is always unitary).

We conclude that the  orthochronous Poincaré group  ${\cal P}_+^\uparrow$ (and consequently the orthochronous Lorentz  group $SO(1,3)^\uparrow$) can only be represented by **unitary** operators in quantum theories, when the action of the group is on **states**.

Non unitary representations arise dropping the last requirement. For instance dealing with Dirac or Weyl spinors.

---

($^*$) Actually a phase could take place, since states are represented by normalized vectors up to phases: $U_gU_h = e^{i\alpha(g,h)}U_{g\cdot h}$, however it does not change the result of the subsequent  reasoning. As a matter of fact, it is possible to prove that  continuous (projective) unitary representations of ${\cal P}_+^\uparrow$ are not affected by such phases, differently form representations of Galileo's group where those phases  play a crucial role.

Comment: Wonderfully explained (I like the bold to emphasize). Do you have any idea where I can find the Wigner theorem with a kind of easy proof?

Comment: Wigner theorem has a very technical proof with many cases unfortunately, I do not know easy proofs. You could try this paper, for a relatively recent attempt to simplify original Wigner's proof arXiv:0808.0779

Comment: @LoveLearning: you can also make use of the fundamental theorem of projective geometry, but if you want to start from scratch, that just shifts the burden around

Comment: Sure, that is a nice way, but it is not elementary: One should know the fundamental theorem of p.g. (and its proof). Here is a review on that theorem and Wigner theorem is proved as an application.
Claude-Alain Faure: "An Elementary Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry" Geometriae Dedicata, Vol. 90, Issue 1, pp 145-151, March 2002

Comment: or [arXiv:0712.0997](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0997)

Comment: Varadarajan's textbook on geometry of quantum theories (I do not remember the precise title) includes a proof of Wigner theorem for Hilbert spaces on R, C and H [quaternions]. But, frankly speaking,  I cannot say that this book can be considered elementary in any sense... I think that also the paper I have mentioned in my previous comment includes the three R, C and H  cases.